# A nonlinear second order PDE generalizing the hyperbolic cosine

Tags: partial-differential-equations

The PDE
$$
1 + (\partial f/\partial y)^2 + (\partial f/\partial x)^2 - C \bigl(\partial^2 f/ \partial x^2 \bigr)^2 = 0
$$
for a function $f$ of two real variables $x$ and $y$ and a real parameter $C > 0$ is, for instance, solved by
$$
f(x, y) = \cosh(x)
$$
if $C= 1$. However, that solution does not depend on $y$. Is there an ansatz to find more/all solutions, in particular ones with non-vanishing derivative by $y$? It seems this PDE should be in a well-studied class.